# Type of DCDC Buck Converter for Variable Output

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am checking how to design variable output power supply, with DCDC controller Buck. The idea is, to have 20V in the input(Up to 5A), and have a variable output between 5-16V, and 2A. The point here is, I will use DCDC converter, in this case the idea is to use controller with external MOSFET/s. I have been checking and I am not sure, and that is why I would like to discuss, which should be the best control mode for this application.

Voltage Mode Control

- Robust and consistent response even with parameters changing...
- Slow Response

Current Mode  Control

- Faster response than VM
- The control loop is bit more critical

Hyteretic Mode  Control

- Very fast response
- Frequency changes which affect to the inductor
- Capacitor in feedback needed for good control

I am between the Voltage Mode and Hyteretic Mode.

Since the requirements related to the response speed are not really strict I am thinking to go to the VM.

I have been trying to work and do some tests with the LM3485 from TI (Hysteric Mode), doing some simulations and also stability analysis, but since the Tina suite is not working properly with this Pspice Model and AC simulations, I could not perform this simulations because if I want to change the output voltage (Offsetting the Feedback with DAC or PWM filtered) I need to know if the circuit is stable in all conditions.

Maybe the Hysteric Mode is more suitable to supply Core voltages for processors and this kind of applications which require really good transient response.

Thanks!!

Comment: How fast response do you need? Have you looked at TPS54332?

Comment: The main Purpose is to supply external "boards" this means that fast Response is not needed, because these external boards will have their own decoupling devices… like a "bench" powe supply. I will take a look to the device which you suggested to me. Thanks!!

Comment: This doesn't make sense: *The idea is, to have 20V in the output (Up to 5A), and have a variable output between 5-16V, and 2A.* Also you say this: *I need to know if the circuit is stable in all conditions.* and, who can tell because you haven't posted a circuit?

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry, I have corrected the sentence, "Input". Until know I have not decided yet which controller or DCDC stage I want to use, is only a general statement, that I want to simulate the circuit when I have already have something. I could post the circuitry which I have already designed with the LM3485 but maybe would be better to do in in other post.